# convergence of $ \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^1 |\sin^k(k\pi x) |^p dx = 0 $

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence

Show that $$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^1 |\sin^k(k\pi x) |^p dx = 0  $$ for $p \in \mathbb{N}$ arbitary.

My try, if I subsitute $y=k\pi x, \frac{dy}{dx}=k\pi$
which leads to $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^1 |\sin^k(y)(k\pi)^{-1} |^p dy = 0 $$ and since $sin(y)$ is bounded, I get the zero function, is this correct?

Greetings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing variables with $y = k \pi x$ we get

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 |\sin^k(k\pi x) |^p \,dx &= \frac{1}{k \pi}\int_0^{k \pi} |\sin y |^{pk} \, dy \\  &= \frac{1}{k \pi} \sum_{j=1}^k \int_{j\pi - \pi}^{j \pi}|\sin y |^{pk} \, dy \\ &= \frac{1}{k \pi} \sum_{j=1}^k \int_{0}^{\pi}|\sin y |^{pk} \, dy  \\ &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi}|\sin y |^{pk} \, dy \\ &= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\pi} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{pk+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{pk}{2} + 1\right)} \end{align}$$

Using, for example, Stirling's approximation you can show that the limit as $k \to \infty$ is zero.

Alternatively,

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}|\sin y |^{pk} \, dy  \\ = \int_{0}^{\pi/2 - \epsilon}|\sin y |^{pk} \, dy  + \int_{ \pi/2 - \epsilon}^{\pi/2 + \epsilon}|\sin y |^{pk} \, dy + \int_{ \pi/2 + \epsilon}^{\pi}|\sin y |^{pk} \, dy \\ \leqslant |\sin(\pi/2-\epsilon) |^{pk}(\pi/2 - \epsilon) + 2\epsilon + |\sin(\pi/2+\epsilon) |^{pk}(\pi/2 - \epsilon)$$

Hence, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we get

$$0 \leqslant \liminf_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}|\sin y |^{pk} \, dy \leqslant \limsup_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}|\sin y |^{pk} \, dy  < 2 \epsilon.$$

Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, the limit is zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't there a way to avoid the last line? I tried to drag the limes under the integral, but since $|sin(y)|^{pk}$ doesn't converge uniformly, its probably not possible. ( otherwise, we would have the zero function almost everywhere and the result follows).

Comment: I think now is where you can break the integral into pieces over $[0, \pi/2 - \epsilon] \cup [\pi/2 - \epsilon, \pi/2 + \epsilon] \cup [ \pi/2  + \epsilon, \pi]$ to evaluate limit that way.

Comment: could you explain that a bit further? Thank you.

Comment: Added to answer

Answer (score 3):

The change of variables $x = y/k$ gives

$$\int_0^1 |\sin (k\pi x)|^{kp}\, dx = \frac{1}{k}\int_0^k |\sin(\pi y)|^{kp}\, dy = \int_0^1 |\sin(\pi y)|^{kp}\, dy,$$

where we've used the $1$-periodicity of $|\sin (\pi y)|.$ Now for $y\in [0,1], y\ne 1/2,$ $|\sin (\pi y)|<1.$ Hence for such $y,$ $|\sin (\pi y)|^{kp} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty.$ Since the integrands are all bounded by $1,$ the dominated convergence theorem shows the limit is $0.$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\verts{\sin^{k}\pars{k\pi x}}^{\,p}\,\dd x = 0}$

\begin{align}
\mbox{Note that} &
\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\verts{\sin^{k}\pars{k\pi x}}^{\,p}\,\dd x =
{1 \over \pi}\lim_{k \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over k}
\int_{0}^{k\pi}\verts{\sin^{k}\pars{ x}}^{\,p}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over \pi}\lim_{k \to \infty}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{kp}\pars{x}\,\dd x =
{2 \over \pi}\lim_{k \to \infty}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{kp}\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over \pi}\lim_{k \to \infty}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\exp\pars{kp\ln\pars{\cos\pars{x}}}\,\dd x =
{2 \over \pi}\lim_{k \to \infty}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-kpx^{2}/2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{2 \over \pi}\lim_{k \to \infty}{\root{\pi/2} \over \root{kp}} = \bbx{\large 0}
\,,\qquad p > 0.
\end{align}